# Inspect OperationContext for Credentials.UserName at server side

Tags: .net, wcf

Is it possible to get username and password supplied on client side with this code:

```
myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.UserName = "username";
myChannelFactory.Credentials.UserName.Password = "password";
```

In server side code? Specifically in this method?:

```
public class MyAuthorizationManager : ServiceAuthorizationManager
{
    protected override bool CheckAccessCore(OperationContext operationContext)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you need to do with username and password? Perform custom validation?

Comment: yes. The logic behind doing this in ServiceAuthorizationmanager is that I want to perform aditional check for user being logged in Windows Domain. (I know i could - in simple case - create custom validator for wcf authentication)

Comment: Do you need more than checking whether the user is authenticated and having a specific role?

Comment: I worry that it will not work because during authorization user is already authenticated = credentials are validated and Identity is set.

Comment: Well that is too bad. My problem is really simple I just want my user to have convenient use of application. I will either let him log in "single sign on" manner because he is already in domain or I will ask him for username + password.

Answer (score 0):

Write a class derived from UserNamePasswordValidator, then use it with your WCF service behaviour definition

Override "Validate(string userName, string password)" in your class

then web(app).config follows :

```
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="ClearServiceBehaviour">
      <serviceDebug httpHelpPageEnabled="true" includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true" />
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
      <serviceCredentials>
        <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
            customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyNamespace.MyCustomUserPassAuthenticator, MyAssembly" />
      </serviceCredentials>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

Comment: Yes I know this class but the problem is that I also need to check for WindowsCredentials (in case that user is registered in domain). The point is that I need to get hold of username and password in the CheckAccesscore method, the username and password are for sure in operationContext i just dont know how to get them.